# Quartz scheduler stops working after some time in iis

Tags: quartz-scheduler

When I publish my application to IIS server, quartz scheduler stop working after some time.In my local machine IIS server it works fine.

I need to perform some functionality every day at 11:55 pm.

Answer (score 0):

By default, IIS recycles an application pool after some inactivity time. I guess this is your problem. The application will be just shutdown if nobody uses it. 
While it is possible to make the application pool in IIS to run forever, it is still better to not schedule background tasks using web applications.

Use windows services or just simple Windows Task Scheduler for scheduling.
There are a couple of good solutions for scheduling background tasks with C# in .Net:

- [Topshelf](http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/index.html)
- [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/)

Here is a nice topic about using both solutions ["Setting up windows service with Topshelf and HangFire"](https://medium.com/@madhufuture/setting-up-windows-service-with-topshelf-and-hangfire-e29fcf250600)

Comment: "The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET" https://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/